# Set a Pointer Address in Objective-C to nil

Tags: ios, google-maps, pointers

[image]

In my method polylines are drawn everytime the map markers are moved.
According to the Google Maps iOS documentation setting the polyline to nil will remove the polyline.

When I do that after the marker movement fires the polylines remain.

According to other posts on here the GMSPolyline can only be removed if you have the pointer address of the line you want to remove, because even declared globally the api still creates another instance everytime.

I don't know much about pointers or addresses. How does one get the pointer address and once you do how do you reference the object by that address once you get it?

I can get the address like this:

```
NSString *addressRight = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%p",polylineRightPreview];
```

Everytime the method is called even though the variable is declared globally I get a different address each time for GMSPolyline:

```
0x600000d36f80   0x620000d2dfc0    0x608001538560
```

I basically need this:

```
GMSPolyline *polyline = nil;
```

but it has to reference the exact pointer address of the last one created. How do you set

```
0x600000d36f80 to nil?
```

If you just call polyline = nil nothing will happen because once it has been added to the map it has it's own pointer address. Also, calling the map clear function isn't useful because it wouldn't be appropriate to remove all the other map objects and redraw them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have polyline objects added in an array & when you want to remove those polylines , iterate over array & set

```
polyline.map = nil
```

Comment: That works. You should fill out your answer to include the fact that an array is essentially an index of pointer addresses. I will then award the bounty. Seems to be the only way to reference pointer addresses.  Thanks!